# PL/SQL Function_get total balance has errors

Tags: plsql

I was trying to create a function that given a customer name, get the total balance of that customer's accounts from the account table(A#, CNAME, BAL).

When compiling in command, I got errors:
line "SELECT SUM(bal) INTO total_a_bal FROM account" ignored

and               line "WHERE account.cname = v_acname" SQL cmd not properly ended.

Please help correct the errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My function is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totbal
    (v_acname IN account.cname%type)
RETURN NUMBER
IS 
    total_a_bal NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    SELECT SUM(bal) INTO total_a_bal FROM account
    group by account.cname
    WHERE account.cname = v_acname;
    RETURN total_a_bal;
END;
/
```

Comment: `account.cname%type` ... what is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the only problem with your function, but the `WHERE` clause always precedes the `GROUP BY` clause in a SQL query.  Hence, your function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totbal
    (v_acname IN varchar2)     -- a type should follow IN, e.g. varchar2
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    total_a_bal NUMBER; 
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(bal) INTO total_a_bal
    FROM account
    WHERE account.cname = v_acname;    -- WHERE always precedes GROUP BY
    GROUP BY account.cname
RETURN total_a_bal;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments!! I put the where clause before group by and reran the code and got the result! 
For this part: (v_acname IN account.cname%type), it means parameter v_acname has the same datatype as column cname in account table. And this worked too.

Comment: I don't think Oracle works that way.  You should just list the same type as it appeared in the `account` table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `I don't think Oracle works that way` Why? there is possible to use `%type` attribute as type of  UDF argument. Or I incorrect understood something?

Comment: @OtoShavadze I have zero experience with UDF in Oracle.  If you are right then feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Nah, I just checked if I missed something )) I don't want to edit your answer, it seems correct anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle not only works with the parameter definition "account.cname%type" that is preferred method. What it does is to bind the parameter definition to the column in the database. If the column definition is changed the procedure automatically gets the changed.

This concept of defining in terms of data base columns can (and perhaps should) be extended into the variables and return types of the procedure/function itself.

This function then becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totbal
    (v_acname IN account.cname%type)
RETURN account.bal%type
IS 
    total_a_bal account.bal%type; 
BEGIN 
    SELECT SUM(bal) INTO total_a_bal FROM account
    group by account.cname
    WHERE account.cname = v_acname;
    RETURN total_a_bal;
END;
```